# Significance of the last scene of "Yes Man"

Tags: yes-man

I could not understand the significance of the last scene in the movie [Yes Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1068680/) where we see spectators to the show came to attend the show nudely. Is there any meaning of this scene? Did Carl do it to humiliate in someway Terrace, the host of the show, to make him understand his philosophy is only half-true? I did not understand this part.

Answer (score 6):

You see him just before that scene donating a large amount of clothing to a charity. It's his way of taking revenge on the philosophy/person that nearly destroyed his life (but also kind of made it). He just used the blind obedience of the Yes-people to have them donating to the charity. It shows Terrance that he should mention to his followers the stuff he said to Carl in the hospital.

Comment: Yes. Exactly! And bonus points for brevity.